# Evaluating a double integral involving `MittagLefflerE`

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, special-functions

Here is the double integral, I want to evaluate and then plot.

```
Clear[z, k, t, tau];

N1 = 1; (*N1 is in fact infinity*)

alpha = 1; 

u[z_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, alpha_?NumericQ] := 2/Pi*NIntegrate[k*Sin[k*z]* 
NIntegrate[Cos[t - tau]*tau^(alpha - 1)*MittagLefflerE[alpha, alpha, -k^2*tau^alpha],
     {tau, 0, t}], {k, 0, N1}]
```

One of the integral involves `MittagLefflerE`, which seems to be causing the warnings.

when I try,

```
u[1, Pi/2, 1]
```

I get

> NIntegrate::inumr:

and then an output.

I even tried `Normal[Series[MittagLefflerE[alpha, alpha, -k^2*tau^alpha], {tau, 0, 2}]]`.

But when I try to plot `u` for different values of `t`, accept all those warnings, it take ages.

```
Plot[{u[z, Pi/2, 1], u[z, 3*Pi/2, 1], u[z, Pi, 1], u[z, 2*Pi, 1]}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

But so far no luck. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why didn't you bundle it all up in a single `NIntegrate[]`? `u[z_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := With[{α = 1}, 2/π NIntegrate[k Sin[k z] Cos[t - τ] τ^(α - 1) MittagLefflerE[α, α, -k^2 τ^α], {k, 0, ∞}, {τ, 0, t}]]; Plot[Table[u[z, t], {t, π/2, 2 π, π/2}] // Evaluate, {z, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @J.M. I am trying your suggestion for the last 10 mins and its still running....

Comment: Well, [I got it to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiGDH.png), even tho it takes long.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function of the inner integration an call it

```
nint1[t_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[
     Cos[t - tau]*tau^(alpha - 1)*
     MittagLefflerE[alpha, alpha, -k^2*tau^alpha], {tau, 0, t}]


u[z_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, alpha_?NumericQ] := 
    2/Pi*NIntegrate[k*Sin[k*z]*nint1[t, k], {k, 0, N1}]
```

For me this workes very well.

Comment: This work flawlessly for this particular case. But when I change `alpha=0.8` and `{z,0,10}`, then it is still running for the last 2 hours.